# Hardware doesn't work some times at boot time

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, asus-laptop

I have an Asus n51vf laptop. I bought it not long time ago (less than a month) and installed Windows 7 on it. Since that it wasn't new when I bought it, I don't know, if the problem was occuring before re-installing Windows 7.

There are two problems, that might (or might not) have something to do with each other:

**Problem**

The less annoying problem is that the screen flickers ONLY on YouTube when scrolling and/or pausing/playing the video or moving the curser over the video.

The second more time-consuming problem is that some of the hardware doesn't work when I turn up the computer. Then I have to reboot the computer and try again.

Example: I turn on the computer, and the touchpad doesn't work - I then reboot and it works again. This has so far happened to the screen (leading to a black screen), the keyboard and the touchpad. More frequently the mouse.

**What have I tried to do so far?**

I tried reinstalling the touchpad driver (Synaptic Touchpad driver from [Asus Support Page](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=N51Vf&p=3&s=161&os=29&hashedid=0Tc42s23bOdbbvY5)) - didn't help at all. I even tried reinstalling the driver when the non-responding mouse on startup-problem occured (using the keyboard), but it asked me to reboot and didn't help at all.
I also installed (and reinstalled) the graphics driver; it's a GeForce GT 130M.

Now, the problem never occurs spontaneously - it only appears when booting my computer. I can even use the computer for heavy tasks (games, multiple programs running etc.) with no problem at all.

I suspect, that the problem is in some booting mechanism that fails: maybe the Windows driver loading? Motherboard problems?

Comment: have you checked if there is a chipset or bios driver update available for you laptop? be careful with bios updates though, if you don't follow the instructions it might render your computer unusable.